Mui V6 integration with pwa-studio 12.4
I'm getting this error $RefreshSig$ is not defined apparently with @apollo/client
Uncaught ReferenceError: $RefreshReg$ is not defined
    at ../lafam-ui/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloProvider.js (vendors.8f80e60e234cd2ccd10f.js:62252:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:86:1)
    at ./src/index.js (client.js:94457:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:86:1)
    at 0 (client.js:223667:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:86:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at bootstrap:227:1
    at bootstrap:227:1

this happens beacuse i tried to update mui v5 from mui v6 and it now works with modules
this is my package.json
{
    "name": "@magento/lafam-concept",
    "version": "12.4.0",
    "publishConfig": {
        "access": "public"
    },
    "description": "Venia PWA Concept Storefront for Magento 2",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "browser": {
        "@magento/venia-drivers": "src/drivers"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "yarn run build:prod",
        "build:dev": "yarn run clean && webpack --no-progress --env.mode development",
        "build:prod": "yarn run clean && webpack --no-progress --env.mode production",
        "start": "buildpack serve .",
        "start:debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --color --env.mode development",
        "test": "yarn run -s prettier:check && yarn run -s lint && jest",
        "watch": "webpack-dev-server --progress --color --env.mode development"
    },
    "repository": "github:magento/pwa-studio",
    "author": "Adobe Commerce",
    "license": "(OSL-3.0 OR AFL-3.0)",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/tree/main/packages/venia-concept#readme",
    "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/luxon": "^2.14.0",
        "@emotion/react": "~11.13.3",
        "@emotion/styled": "~11.13.0",
        "@magento/pwa-buildpack": "~11.3.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "~6.1.5",
        "@mui/lab": "~6.0.0-beta.13",
        "@mui/material": "~6.1.5",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers": "6.8.0",
        "date-fns": "~2.30.0",
        "dayjs": "~1.11.8",
        "luxon": "~3.3.0",
        "react-gtm-module": "~2.0.11",
        "react-hook-form": "7.34.0",
        "react-imask": "^6.4.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@adobe/apollo-link-mutation-queue": "~1.0.2",
        "@apollo/client": "~3.5.0",
        "@babel/core": "~7.15.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "~7.14.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "~7.14.7",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "~7.21.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "~7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "~7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "~7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "~7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "~7.14.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "~7.4.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "~7.16.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "~7.15.3",
        "@magento/babel-preset-peregrine": "~1.2.1",
        "@magento/eslint-config": "~1.5.0",
        "@magento/lafam-ui": "~9.4.0",
        "@magento/pagebuilder-lafam": "~7.3.0",
        "@magento/peregrine": "~12.4.0",
        "@magento/pwa-theme-venia": "~1.3.0",
        "@magento/upward-security-headers": "~1.0.8",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.4.1",
        "@storybook/react": "~6.3.7",
        "@types/node": "16",
        "@types/react": "~18.2.6",
        "@types/react-dom": "~18.2.4",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "~5.3.3",
        "apollo-cache-persist": "~0.1.1",
        "babel-core": "~7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-eslint": "~10.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "~24.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "~8.0.5",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "~2.3.3",
        "babel-plugin-graphql-tag": "~2.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "~3.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-react-remove-properties": "~0.3.0",
        "braintree-web-drop-in": "~1.16.0",
        "compression": "~1.7.4",
        "css-loader": "~5.2.7",
        "dotenv": "~6.2.0",
        "eslint": "~7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-babel": "~5.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-graphql": "~4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "~6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "~8.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-package-json": "~0.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "~7.21.5",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "~4.2.0",
        "express": "~4.16.4",
        "file-loader": "~4.0.0",
        "graphql": "~15.5.0",
        "graphql-tag": "~2.12.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "~4.5.2",
        "informed": "~3.29.0",
        "jarallax": "~1.11.1",
        "load-google-maps-api": "~2.0.1",
        "lodash": "~4.17.20",
        "lodash.escape": "~4.0.1",
        "lodash.get": "~4.4.2",
        "lodash.over": "~4.7.0",
        "lodash.set": "~4.3.2",
        "memoize-one": "~5.0.0",
        "memory-fs": "~0.4.1",
        "node-fetch": "~2.3.0",
        "postcss": "~8.3.6",
        "postcss-loader": "~4.3.0",
        "prettier": "~1.16.4",
        "prop-types": "~15.7.2",
        "react": "~17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "~17.0.1",
        "react-imask": "^6.4.2",
        "react-intl": "~5.20.0",
        "react-redux": "~7.2.2",
        "react-refresh": "0.8.3",
        "react-router-dom": "~5.2.0",
        "react-slick": "~0.28.0",
        "react-tabs": "~3.1.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "~17.0.1",
        "redux": "~4.0.1",
        "redux-actions": "~2.6.4",
        "redux-thunk": "~2.3.0",
        "rimraf": "~2.6.3",
        "style-loader": "~2.0.0",
        "subscriptions-transport-ws": "~0.9.19",
        "tailwindcss": "~2.2.7",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "~1.2.3",
        "url-loader": "~4.1.1",
        "uuid": "~8.3.2",
        "webpack": "~4.46.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~3.3.2",
        "webpack-cli": "~3.2.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "~3.2.1",
        "workbox-cacheable-response": "~6.2.4",
        "workbox-core": "~6.2.4",
        "workbox-expiration": "~6.2.4",
        "workbox-precaching": "~6.2.4",
        "workbox-routing": "~6.2.4",
        "workbox-strategies": "~6.2.4",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "~6.2.4"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "sharp": "~0.29.3"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.x",
        "yarn": ">=1.12.0"
    },
    "module": "src/index.js",
    "es2015": "src/index.js",
    "esnext": "src/index.js",
    "pwa-studio": {
        "targets": {
            "intercept": "./local-intercept.js"
        }
    }
}


this is my webpack.config.js
const { configureWebpack, graphQL } = require('@magento/pwa-buildpack');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const {
    getMediaURL,
    getStoreConfigData,
    getAvailableStoresConfigData,
    getPossibleTypes
} = graphQL;

const { DefinePlugin } = webpack;
// const { LimitChunkCountPlugin } = webpack.optimize;

const getCleanTemplate = templateFile => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.readFile(templateFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            resolve(
                data.replace(
                    /(?<inlineddata><!-- Inlined Data -->.*\s<!-- \/Inlined Data -->)/gs,
                    ''
                )
            );
        });
    });
};

module.exports = async env => {
    /**
     * configureWebpack() returns a regular Webpack configuration object.
     * You can customize the build by mutating the object here, as in
     * this example. Since it's a regular Webpack configuration, the object
     * supports the `module.noParse` option in Webpack, documented here:
     * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulenoparse
     */
    const config = await configureWebpack({
        context: __dirname,
        vendor: [
            '@apollo/client',
            'apollo-cache-persist',
            'informed',
            'react',
            'react-dom',
            'react-feather',
            'react-redux',
            'react-idle-timer',
            'react-router-dom',
            'redux',
            'redux-actions',
            'redux-thunk'
        ],
        special: {
            'react-feather': {
                esModules: true
            },
            'react-idle-timer': {
                esModules: true
            }
        },
        env
    });

    const mediaUrl = await getMediaURL();
    const storeConfigData = await getStoreConfigData();
    const { availableStores } = await getAvailableStoresConfigData();
    const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

    /**
     * Loop the available stores when there is provided STORE_VIEW_CODE
     * in the .env file, because should set the store name from the
     * given store code instead of the default one.
     */
    const availableStore = availableStores.find(
        ({ code }) => code === process.env.STORE_VIEW_CODE
    );

    global.MAGENTO_MEDIA_BACKEND_URL = mediaUrl;
    global.LOCALE = storeConfigData.locale.replace('_', '-');
    global.AVAILABLE_STORE_VIEWS = availableStores;

    const possibleTypes = await getPossibleTypes();

    const htmlWebpackConfig = {
        filename: 'index.html',
        minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true
        }
    };

    // Strip UPWARD mustache from template file during watch
    if (
        process.env.npm_lifecycle_event &&
        process.env.npm_lifecycle_event.includes('watch')
    ) {
        const devTemplate = await getCleanTemplate('./template.html');

        // Generate new gitignored html file based on the cleaned template
        await writeFile('template.generated.html', devTemplate);
        htmlWebpackConfig.template = './template.generated.html';
    } else {
        htmlWebpackConfig.template = './template.html';
    }

    config.module.noParse = [
        /@adobe\/adobe\-client\-data\-layer/,
        /braintree\-web\-drop\-in/
    ];
    config.plugins = [
        ...config.plugins,
        new DefinePlugin({
            /**
             * Make sure to add the same constants to
             * the globals object in jest.config.js.
             */
            POSSIBLE_TYPES: JSON.stringify(possibleTypes),
            STORE_NAME: availableStore
                ? JSON.stringify(availableStore.store_name)
                : JSON.stringify(storeConfigData.store_name),
            STORE_VIEW_CODE: process.env.STORE_VIEW_CODE
                ? JSON.stringify(process.env.STORE_VIEW_CODE)
                : JSON.stringify(storeConfigData.code),
            AVAILABLE_STORE_VIEWS: JSON.stringify(availableStores),
            DEFAULT_LOCALE: JSON.stringify(global.LOCALE),
            DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE: JSON.stringify(
                process.env.DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE || 'US'
            ),
            __DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
        }),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin(htmlWebpackConfig)
    ];
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.otf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 10000,
                mimetype: 'font/otf'
            }
        }
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(webp)$/i,
        use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                mimetype: 'image/webp'
            }
        }
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(mp4)$/i,
        use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                mimetype: 'video/mp4'
            }
        }
    });

// I added this lines to configure loaders for mui from here

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$/, // Añadimos soporte para JavaScript moderno y TypeScript
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@mui\/material|@mui\/system|@mui\/utils|@mui\/base)\/).*/, // Procesamos MUI y otras dependencias específicas si es necesario
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env', // Para transpilar el código ES6+
                    '@babel/preset-react' // Para transpilar JSX
                ],
                plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining', // Soporte para el operador "?."
                    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator' // Soporte para el operador "??"
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    // Añadir 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' en cada entrada
    if (typeof config.entry === 'object') {
        for (const entryName in config.entry) {
            if (Array.isArray(config.entry[entryName])) {
                config.entry[entryName] = [
                    'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
                    ...config.entry[entryName]
                ];
            } else if (typeof config.entry[entryName] === 'string') {
                config.entry[entryName] = [
                    'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
                    config.entry[entryName]
                ];
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof config.entry === 'string') {
        config.entry = ['regenerator-runtime/runtime', config.entry];
    } else if (Array.isArray(config.entry)) {
        config.entry = ['regenerator-runtime/runtime', ...config.entry];
    } else {
        console.warn(
            'Tipo de config.entry no reconocido. Asegúrate de manejarlo correctamente.'
        );
    }
// to here
    return [config];
};


And I added this babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@magento/peregrine', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'
    ]
};

Does any of you have tried something similar? or have another approach on how to implement mui v6 with magento pwa-studio 12.4?
thanks in advance
